# Performance wise will iOS extension files help in rendering big assets faster ?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails

We have a mobile app that builds its UI , partly via large video / animation files. Today we apply calls to our server to retrieve these assets . The problem is that the app's graphics is loading instantly aside for these assets that are loading ...

We are thinking of moving these large assets from where they are today ( on our servers ) to be part of the extension files ( up to 4 GB ) that appstore / google play offer. Question is : from your experience, will this change help render these big  assets faster to the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iOS app extensions are modular programs that let you offer your app's functionality outside of your app. Think of them as widgets. They are not intended for, or suitable for, packaging assets.

So the answer is no.